# Expected primary-expression before '.' token

Tags: c++, templates

I've been battling this for a while and looking around but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

The error:

error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

is popping up for most of the code inside the addElement method
where BinaryNode.variable is concerned but I'm completely lost on what to do here

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
using namespace std;

template <typename Comparable>
BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::BinarySearchTree(const Comparable & theElement, BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *leftTree,
BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *rightTree) : BinaryNode(theElement,leftTree,rightTree) {
}

template <typename Comparable> 
void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::addElement(Comparable newElement) {
    if(newElement < BinaryNode.element) {
        if(BinaryNode.left == NULL) {
            BinaryNode.left = BinarySearchTree(newElement, NULL, NULL);
            BinaryNode.right.root = BinaryNode;
        } else {
            BinaryNode.left.addElement(newElement);
        }
    } else if (newElement > BinaryNode.element) {
        if(BinaryNode.right == NULL) {
            BinaryNode.right = BinarySearchTree(newElement, NULL, NULL);
            BinaryNode.right.root = this;
        } else {
            BinaryNode.right.addElement(newElement);
        }
    }
```

And here's the header file for BinarySearchTree

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename Comparable>
class BinarySearchTree {
public:
    BinarySearchTree(const Comparable & theElement, BinarySearchTree<Comparable> * leftTree, 
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable> * rightTree);
    void addElement(Comparable newElement);
    void removeElement(Comparable newElement);
    BinarySearchTree<Comparable> * findElement(Comparable newElement);
    bool isEmpty();
    BinarySearchTree & operator=(const BinarySearchTree &tree);
    vector<BinarySearchTree> preOrder(vector<BinarySearchTree> * list);
    vector<BinarySearchTree> inOrder();
    vector<BinarySearchTree> postOrder();

private:
    struct BinaryNode {
        Comparable element;
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *left;
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *right;

        BinaryNode( const Comparable & theElement, BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *leftTree,
        BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *rightTree) : element(theElement), left(leftTree), right(rightTree){}
     };

     BinaryNode *root;
 };
```

Comment: Please indicate which line the error occurs on.

Comment: It's for every BinaryNode reference in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `BinaryNode` as a variable name, but it's a type.  You can't use the `.` operator on a type, just on an object. For example:

```
if(newElement < root->element) {
    if(root->left == NULL) {
        root->left = BinarySearchTree(newElement, NULL, NULL);
        root->right->root = new BinaryNode;
    } else {
        root->left->addElement(newElement);
    }
```

Notice I changed to `->` as well, since you have pointers everywhere, too.

Comment: Root would be the parent BinaryNode. How would I go about getting the element variable inside the BinaryNode struct inside the current class?  I haven't used structs much and it's non-editable in my assignment

Comment: I've made an error in understanding what the design was expected to be, thanks for the help.