# expected primary-expression before '.' token

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am getting the error: 
`expected primary-expression before '.' token`
in the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    struct a {
        int y;
    };

    int n = 0;
    n = a.y;

    std::cout << "n: " << n << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc g++ compiler and Syntastic in vim. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: you didn't instantiate a. try struct a b; n=b.y;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected primary-expression before '.' token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817789/expected-primary-expression-before-token)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is a **type** and **not an object**.

You need to create an instance of `a` prior to using any member of it:

```
a b = { 1 };

int n = 0;
n = b.y;

std::cout << "n: " << n << "\n";
```